# preg_replace equivalent in java

Tags: java, android

How to convert this code into java code

```
$response = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $response);
```

I try this

```
String jsonStr = "Some Json string";
jsonStr.replaceAll("/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/", "");
```

But it show an error

```
Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60830223/6533853

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the backslashes with another backslash like this:

```
jsonStr.replaceAll("[\\x00-\\x1F\\x80-\\xFF]", "");
```

Backslashes in strings introduce special characters in Java.

Comment: I am getting a json string from a website.  json string contains ` ï»¿` in start point. Now I how I remove this. I try with this code in `php` and it works for me. but I cant do it in android. can you please give any advice?

Comment: In Java you don't need a delimiter for the regex. Thus removing the slashes should give you the same result as in PHP. I updated the answer.